# Blocked.com free trial script shows blank page

Tags: php, xampp, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean, blocked

Here's what I'm trying to do: https://www.blocked.com/install.php

I've tried locally with XAMPP and on DigitalOcean with LEMP and LAMP on Ubuntu 14.04, all of them with the same result: Step 4 shows a blank page.

Is there anything I'm missing or is it their fault?

Comment: Hard to say, do they have support/a forum? Did you contact them? We'd have to practically "install" it in order to test it; and I for one, am **not** going $to. `$to = "install/test";`

Comment: It's always your fault.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Did you even try to understand what this is? You don't need to install any program, it's a PHP script.

Comment: Install in my mind, means installing on my server and testing. Plus, see my comment under your answer being *"Not sure why don't they say that is required to run their script."* - Did you even bother reading the FAQ before posting? *"**What are the system requirements?**

    The software is compatible with PHP versions PHP 4.0.1 - 5.5.x and requires **Ioncube PHP loaders** and at least 20 MB of disk space."* https://www.blocked.com/faq.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem was.

I had to enable errors to see what was going on, and apparently I need(ed) to install IonCube Loader on the server.

```
//error_reporting(0); ini_set('display_errors', 0);

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Also, they check if you have IonCube Loader in your system AFTER using it... Makes sense.

```
$version_ioncube = ioncube_loader_version();

Fatal error: Call to undefined function ioncube_loader_version() in /usr/share/nginx/html/blockscript/install.php on line 18
```

On line 33:

```
# check if ionCube is installed
if (!function_exists('ioncube_loader_version')) {
    print_message('<b>Warning:</b> ionCube is not installed. ionCube is required to run the Blocked software. Please <a href="http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php" target="_blank">download latest version of the ionCube Loaders</a> for your server. You can refer to the <a href="http://www.ioncube.com/loader_installation.php" target="_blank">ionCube Loader Installation Manual</a> for instructions and help.');
}
```

Comment: *"Not sure why don't they say that is required to run their script."* - Did you even bother reading the FAQ before posting? *"**What are the system requirements?**

    The software is compatible with PHP versions PHP 4.0.1 - 5.5.x and requires **Ioncube PHP loaders** and at least 20 MB of disk space."* https://www.blocked.com/faq.php

Comment: How to not give users instructions for their paid service. Anyway, I don't know why everyone on this site is so rude, it is really that hard to give a respectfully answer to other people's problems? If I'm posting here it's because I didn't find the solution.

Comment: Look, don't get us wrong, we like helping people, including myself; but, no one here is going to install any additional software (such as IonCube Loader) to test what's wrong, not me anyway. When in doubt and in the future, the steps to take are: 1) Contact support 2) Check their FAQ and/or forums. Your question doesn't fall under something we can do to help, while trying to rule or rule out the potential problems a script may have. I do admire the fact that you found the core problem after enabling error reporting which is crucial during development.

Comment: Btw, did you restart your server, or is it working for you now?

Comment: It's working properly after installing IonCube Loader. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I removed my DV from your question btw, and +1 your answer for finding the error yourself, thought I'd give you a break; we all need one every once in a while ;) *cheers* glad it got resolved.